# iphone Gdata youtube api limit the number of videos recieved

Tags: iphone, limit, youtube-api, gdata-api

Hy I'm trying to get all the videos from a user and put them in a list view. I folowed a tutorial on how to do this on iphone and came up whit this. But since this particular user has over 500 videos this method thakes a lot of time to load up the video titles. I saw that ther is a method to get the videos troug a link 
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/PsyStarcraft/uploads?max-results=50&start-index=51`
Any ideeas on how to load them all but whithout making the phone user wait?

```
'GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;
NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"HuskyStarcraft"
                                                     userFeedID:uploadsID];

[service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                 delegate:self
        didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

[super viewDidLoad];'
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the address for the tutorial please ? I know that this topic is old but I really need to found a good tutorial to integrate and use correctly the GData API..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this but query setMaxResults won't work. Set start index works fine. Any ideeas?

```
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

        NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;
        NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:ytid
                                                             userFeedID:uploadsID
                          ];

            NSLog(@"%@", [feedURL path]);
        GDataQueryYouTube* query = [GDataQueryYouTube  youTubeQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
        [query setStartIndex:1];
        [query setMaxResults:2];



            [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                               delegate:self
                      didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

---

Later, solved it:

```
- (GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *)youTubeService {
static GDataServiceGoogleYouTube* _service = nil;

if (!_service) {
    _service = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];

    [_service setUserAgent:@"AppWhirl-UserApp-1.0"];
    [_service setShouldCacheDatedData:YES];
    [_service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:NO];
}

// fetch unauthenticated
[_service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:nil
                                password:nil];

return _service;
}
```

The modified line is

> [_service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:NO];

By the way this is modified from this code: http://pastebin.com/vmV2c0HT

Comment: final modification and it WORKS!! :D